# php - check login

Tags: php, hash, mysqli

i have a problem with my code, i need to check an hash value in the db, but the hash never match to the stored, so login is not permit (if i change to normal text it is permit, then the problem is the hash)

I have two alternatives, but none works

first: i don't know what is the problem in this code

```
<?php 

$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_port = 3306;
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = 'xxx';
$db_name = 'emprego';

$db = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name, $db_port);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
fail('MySQL connect', mysqli_connect_error());

require('PasswordHash.php');

$name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);

$myPassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['myPassword']);

$pwdHasher = new PasswordHash(8, FALSE);

$hash = $pwdHasher->HashPassword( $myPassword);

($stmt = $db->prepare('select pass from users where username=?'))
|| fail('MySQL prepare', $db->error);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name)
|| fail('MySQL bind_param', $db->error);
$stmt->execute()
|| fail('MySQL execute', $db->error);
$stmt->bind_result($hash)
|| fail('MySQL bind_result', $db->error);
if (!$stmt->fetch() && $db->errno)
fail('MySQL fetch', $db->error);

if ($pwdHasher->CheckPassword($myPassword, $hash)) {
    echo "yes";
} else {
    echo "no"; 
}

?>
```

second alternative: the hash never matches because it is generated a new one, i think

```
<?php 
include("includes/f_banco.php");
conecta ();

require('PasswordHash.php');

$name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);

$myPassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['myPassword']);

$pwdHasher = new PasswordHash(8, FALSE);

$hash = $pwdHasher->HashPassword( $myPassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$name."' and pass='".$hash."' ";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
    echo "yes";
}
else
echo "no"; 

?>
```

any help? i just need one of both.

Thanks :)

Comment: What does that PasswordHash function do? What happens if you run it twice in a row with the same inputs. Does it return the same hash, or something different? If the two values are different, then it's most likely using some random salt which you'd have to store along with hashed password.

Comment: the result is a different hash, this have a salt, it is the reason, so the hash never matches

Comment: You'll have to get the salt, then, or use a different hashing library. There's no need to use an external one. just use `sha1()` and make your own salt. It's not hard.

Comment: i prefer a good class, that have been done by experts, that is not my case, i posted how i  solved the issue. thanks for help Marc B

Comment: Since it's screwing up your login, it's not a good class. Either it provides some method of retrieving the salt it created, or it's useless for your purposes.

Comment: yes, it is CheckPassword. now everything works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved with this code

```
 <?php

require '../PasswordHash.php';

$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_port = 3306;
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = 'xxx';
$db_name = 'emprego';

$hash_cost_log2 = 8;

$hash_portable = FALSE;

$debug = TRUE;


function get_post_var($var)
{
    $val = $_POST[$var];
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        $val = stripslashes($val);
    return $val;
}

$user = get_post_var('name');
$pass = get_post_var('myPassword');

$db = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name, $db_port);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    fail('MySQL connect', mysqli_connect_error());

$hasher = new PasswordHash($hash_cost_log2, $hash_portable);

    ($stmt = $db->prepare('select pass from users where username=?'))
        || fail('MySQL prepare', $db->error);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $user)
        || fail('MySQL bind_param', $db->error);
    $stmt->execute()
        || fail('MySQL execute', $db->error);
    $stmt->bind_result($hash)
        || fail('MySQL bind_result', $db->error);
    if (!$stmt->fetch() && $db->errno)
        fail('MySQL fetch', $db->error);

    if ($hasher->CheckPassword($pass, $hash)) {
        $what = 'yes';
    } else {
        $what = 'no';
    }

echo "$what";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you tagged your question as PDO but you're using the mysqli interface. I suggest you actually use PDO.

Some suggestions while lacking more details:

- I don't understand what your "hashing class" does as its code is not written; check that it uses the same hashing algorithm that was used to store the password
- do not escape the password if you're going to hash it anyway
- use the second kind of check (with clauses both on user and pass), it's just more straightforward

Assuming you know how the password was originally hashed before being saved to the database, just repeat the same process. If no salt was used, then don't use any salt during the check. If `sha1()` was used rather than `md5()`, then directly use that function and drop the external class (unless you need any other functionality from it).

Comment: the reason why the passwords never match is the salt. How can solve this?

Comment: change the hashing function? You should know how the password in the database was hashed, just do the same.